# SwiftGif: This image named "one" does not exist

Tags: swift, xcode

Followed the instructions from video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm61mxcSD4U&t=95s

Added my animated GIF file, `one.GIF`.

Tried running, but get error:

> SwiftGif: This image named "one" does not exist.

[image: Xcode Navigator]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gifView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gifView.loadGif(name: "one")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Great first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file `one.GIF`, the extension is all uppercase. However, you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/blob/1a4ad1089c3a627037288d43924b40ccc0f229b7/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift#L65-L68) that it's looking for lowercase `.gif`.

You need to rename `one.GIF` to `one.gif`.

---

From [Getting References to Bundle Resources: The Bundle Search Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7):

> **Important**: The bundle interfaces consider case when searching for resource files in the bundle directory. This case-sensitive search occurs even on file systems (such as HFS+) that are not case sensitive when it comes to file names.

Comment: upvoted for humble attitude in the comments section :)